# Android :The unit of imageLayout.getHeight

Tags: android, image, height, width, pixel

I'm creating an  imageLyout in xml file ,using this code this code :

```
    <com.manuelpeinado.imagelayout.ImageLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:custom="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/image_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#aaa"
    custom:fit="both"
    custom:image="@drawable/plan"
    custom:imageHeight="1744"
    custom:imageWidth="1150" >
 </com.manuelpeinado.imagelayout.ImageLayout>
```

When i enter to the image in the drawbale-hdpi properties i see that image dimensions are : 515 * 348 pixels.

And when i i use this java code :

```
                     hauteurLayout = imageLayout.getHeight();
             largeurLayout = imageLayout.getWidth() ;
```

I get this result : 407 * 601 .

Well i'm confused about all those dimensions, why are they differents and they are representing the same image ?

And i need to draw something in a map ,so i need to kwow the right dimensions that i have to use, to draw the object in the exact place.

And this is the image (i'm using horizontalScreeView ):

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To support multiple screen resolutions, you should use density independent pixels (dip), also known as dp.
This is a scaling method to scale from px (which depend on the screen resolution) to dp (which scale well on every device):

```
private final int px2dp(int px)
{
    final float scale = getResources().getSystem().getDisplayMetrics().density;
    return (int) (px * scale);
}
```

Comment: I'm getting the same result :les hauteur et largeur(11543): 407 * 601 `hauteurLayout = imageLayout.getHeight();
           largeurLayout = imageLayout.getWidth() ;
           Log.i("les hauteur et largeur", px2dp(hauteurLayout)  +" * "+ px2dp(largeurLayout) );` @Der Golem

Comment: What is your screen resolution in dpi?

Comment: sorry but how can i know my screen resolution ,from the device ?

Comment: In many ways. One of them is looking on Google for your device's specs. But you can do that programmatically. Just print out the scale in px2dp. That will tell me if it's a ldpi, mdpi, hdpi, ... device

Comment: my screen resolution is 320*480 .

Comment: Please take a look at the image i added in my post.

Comment: **320*480** is **typically** an **mdpi** resolution **for phones** (**160 dpi**). Luckyly, this is the "**normal**" resolution, so **px = dp**, since the scale is **1.0**

Comment: Aaaa ok :). So if i want to draw something in that image:map (you can see it in the post ), i have to concider my height and widht : 407 and 601 that i'm getting from getHeight and hetWidht ? @Der Golem

Comment: Scale your drawing to fit the screen scale. Also coordinates must be scaled, not only sizes.

Comment: I just need your confirmation, please tell me if i inderstood or not. Well if the widht of my map is 601px , and it represents 10 meters (in real life ). Then i have to devide 601/10=60.1. It means 1 meter is represented by 60.1 pixel . Right or not ?

Comment: Yes, it seems to be correct. Obviously, a px is a physical unit, so it doesn't have decimals. This will lead to approximations.

Comment: So i'll take 60 . Thank you very much for your help, sorry if i weisted your time.

Comment: It'n not wasted time. By the way, your app seems interesting. Like interior design / floor planning. Nice idea.

Answer (score 0):

Always use dp while giving dimen to layouts in xml.

To get back exact value,
get the value in px and convert to dp using:

```
int dpToPx(final int dp)
{
return (int) (dp * editText.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density + 0.5f);
}
```

Comment: I'm getting the same result :les hauteur et largeur(11543): 407 * 601 `hauteurLayout = imageLayout.getHeight();            largeurLayout = imageLayout.getWidth() ;            Log.i("les hauteur et largeur", px2dp(hauteurLayout)  +" * "+ px2dp(largeurLayout) ); ` @Anand

Comment: Sorry for thee late reply, but looks like u solved the issue.